# Unable to pass the data after action is called in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, es5-shim

I'm new to redux. I'm using ES5 in my project. I've just started implementing redux in this.

```
main.js:
let store = createStore(rootReducer); //Reducer defined in reducer.js file
class RenderClass extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={hashHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
                    <Route name="employees" path="/employees" url="http://localhost:8080/" component={EmployeeTable}></Route>
                    .....
                </Route>
            <Router>
        </Provider>
        );
    }
}   

App.jsx:
import * as Actions from './action-creator';
const MainLayout = React.createClass({
                render: function() {

                    const { dispatch, list } = this.props;
                    let actions = bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch);
                    console.log(actions);

                    return (
                        <div className="wrapper">
                            <Header actions={actions} list={list} params={this.props.params} />

                            {this.props.children}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            }); 

function select(state) {
   return {
      list: state.listingReducer
   }
}
export default connect(select)(MainLayout);

header.js:
define(
    [
        'react',
        'jquery',
        'appMin'
    ],
    function (React, $) {
        var Link = require('reactRouter').Link;
        var Header = React.createClass({
            handleClick: function () {
                //Action called here
                this.props.actions.listEmployees();
            },      
            render: function () {
                return (
                    <ul className="sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <Link to={'/employees'} onClick={this.handleClick} list={this.props.list} actions={this.props.actions}><i className="fa fa-home"></i>Employees</Link> 
                        </li> 
                    </ul>
                );
            }
        });
        return Header;
    }
)

employee.js:
define(
    [
        'react',
        'jquery',
        'appMin'
    ],
    function (React, $) {
        var EmployeeTable = React.createClass({

            render: function () {
                if (this.props.list != undefined) {
                    var listItems = this.props.list.map(function (listItem) {
                        return (
                            <tr key={listItem.id}>
                                <td> {listItem.name}</td>
                                ......
                            </tr>
                        );
                    }, this);   
                    })
                }
                return (
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            {listItems}
                        </tbody>                    
                    </table>
                );
            }
        })  
    }
)

action-creator.js:
export function listEmployees() {
    return {
      type: types.LIST_EMPLOYEES
   };
}

reducer.js:
function addEmployee(state, action) {

   switch (action.type) {

      case types.LIST_EMPLOYEES:
         return {"id":"1", "name":"Stackoverflow"}

      default:
        return state
   }
}

function listingReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case types.LIST_EMPLOYEES:
            return [
                ...state, 
                addEmployee(undefined, action)
            ]

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   listingReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

On clicking the "Employees" entry defined in "header.js" file, I'm calling the listEmployees() action and I want to list employees on the screen. But, when I run the project, on clicking the "Employees", the action gets called, later the reducer. But, in the header.js file I see the "this.props.list" updated, but the same when comes to the EmployeeTable it is undefined. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of `mapStateToProps` to make the state listingReducer available as a prop to the EmployeeTable

In your employee.js file after your EmployeeTable React component add this function

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
      return ( list: state.listingReducer)
 }
```

Also you need to import rootReducer in the same file and make use of the connect function from react-redux as

```
export connect(mapStateToProps)(EmployeeTable);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, EmployeeTable is a presentation component. Is it right to make the presentation component to be aware of redux?

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. Plus you need to make the props available to it so that it can render and update on change. That's what redux is for